# Why does exiftool make the current date and time shift?

Tags: windows, macos, date, exif, exiftool

When I try to shift the date and time using exiftool on both OS X and Windows I get the same outcome: the current date and time changed instead of adding 2m 18d 11hr 14m 0s.

exe file and command run from dir `D:\Exif`

```
exiftool "-DateTimeOriginal+=0:2:18 11:14:0" D:\Exif
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "the current date and time changed"? Perhaps you wanted `AllDates` instead of just `DateTimeOriginal`?

Comment: I mean the data I wished to change, changed but to the current date and time I ran the exe. Rather then the + 2m 18d 11hrs 14mins

Answer (score 0):

The time stamp in the file is being shifted by the amount you specify, but the time stamp of the file you are looking at is not the embedded time stamp, it's the file system time stamp, usually what exiftool calls `FileModifyDate`.  This time stamp is supposed to change whenever the file is modified.  If you wish to prevent this change, you can add the [`-P` (preserve) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#P--preserve).